# web scraping html in R

Tags: html, xml, r, web-scraping

I want get the URL list from scraping `http://obamaspeeches.com/P-Obama-Inaugural-Speech-Inauguration.htm` like this:

```
[1] "P-Obama-Inaugural-Speech-Inauguration.htm"
[2] "E11-Barack-Obama-Election-Night-Victory-Speech-Grant-Park-Illinois-November-4-2008.htm"
```

and this is my code:

```
library(XML)

url = "http://obamaspeeches.com/P-Obama-Inaugural-Speech-Inauguration.htm"
doc = htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = T)
url.list = xpathSApply(doc, "//a[contains(@href, 'htm')]")
```

The problem is that I want to `unlist()` `url.list` so I can `strsplit` it but it doesn't `unlist`.

Answer (score 4):

One more step ought to do it (just need to get the `href` attribute):

```
library(XML)

url <- "http://obamaspeeches.com/P-Obama-Inaugural-Speech-Inauguration.htm"
doc <- htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes=TRUE)

url.list <- xpathSApply(doc, "//a[contains(@href, 'htm')]")
hrefs <- gsub("^/", "", sapply(url.list, xmlGetAttr, "href"))

head(hrefs, 6)

## [1] "P-Obama-Inaugural-Speech-Inauguration.htm"                                                                                                 
## [2] "E11-Barack-Obama-Election-Night-Victory-Speech-Grant-Park-Illinois-November-4-2008.htm"                                                    
## [3] "E11-Barack-Obama-Election-Night-Victory-Speech-Grant-Park-Illinois-November-4-2008.htm"                                                    
## [4] "E-Barack-Obama-Speech-Manassas-Virgina-Last-Rally-2008-Election.htm"                                                                       
## [5] "E10-Barack-Obama-The-American-Promise-Acceptance-Speech-at-the-Democratic-Convention-Mile-High-Stadium--Denver-Colorado-August-28-2008.htm"
## [6] "E10-Barack-Obama-The-American-Promise-Acceptance-Speech-at-the-Democratic-Convention-Mile-High-Stadium--Denver-Colorado-August-28-2008.htm"

free(doc)
```

**UPDATE** Obligatory [rvest](http://github.com/hadley/rvest) + `dplyr` way:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

speeches <- html("http://obamaspeeches.com/P-Obama-Inaugural-Speech-Inauguration.htm")
speeches %>% html_nodes("a[href*=htm]") %>% html_attr("href") %>% head(6)

## same output as above
```

Comment: don't forget the `free(doc)` bit when working with `htmlTreeParse()` :-)